# Change table values using a dictionary (if they contain) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I have an HTML table where the headers are included in the first row in `tds`. The reason why I am saying that is because I am not using `ths` at all and I do not want anybody to get confused. The logic is the same.

What I am trying to do is to use a dictionary, in order to replace the multiple rows in my current javascript (Solution First in my snippet).

But with my second solution, I want to see if there is a better option as I am thinking that the for loops might make the code slow.

```js
//First Solution
var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
var columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');

for (var i = 1; i <= columns.length; i++) {
  if (row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML.includes("aaa")) {
    row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML = "AAAA";
  }
  if (row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML.includes("bbb")) {
    row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML = "BBBB";
  }
  if (row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML.includes("ccc")) {
    row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML = "CCCC";
  }
}


//Second Solution
dict = {'aaa':'AAAA', 'bbb':'BBBB', 'ccc':'CCCC'}
for (var key in dict)
{
   for (var i = 1; i <= columns.length; i++) 
   {
     if (row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML.includes(key)) 
     {
        row.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + i + ')').innerHTML = dict[key];
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>aaa header</td><td>bbb header</td><td>ccc header</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ONE</td><td>10000</td><td>30000</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, I don't exactly see a question here but I think you are refering to optimizing the performance of the code?

You can check the time use to run the code on the console as mention in the article below. Haven't try it myself but I myself am starting to explore writing optimized code, so let me know the results if that is what you are looking to do :)

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/measuring-javascript-performance-with-console-time.html

Comment: Yes. I am actually trying to optimise the code. Time counter helps. Although, if you come up with a suggestion regarding the format/syntax... it would be great!

Comment: Mm, the difference in the run time of the code doesn't seem to differ that much (but I didn't do so many test cases, so can't say much!) 
I'm no expert myself in that but this question really interest me. This will be interesting:  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch04s02.html

For if statements, loop in "if ... else if", so that if conditions are met, it will stop going thru the statement in each loop. 
For your second solution, if you include a console.log('num of loops' + i), you will see that your loop continues on for 9 times.

Comment: `var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
var columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
var tdTag = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
dict2 = {'aaa header':'AAAA', 'bbb header':'BBBB', 'ccc header':'CCCC'}
for (var i = 0; i <= tdTag.length -1 ; i++) {
  var textToCheck = tdTag[i].textContent
  var isHeadingValid = dict2.hasOwnProperty(textToCheck) ? true : false
  if ( isHeadingValid ) {
    tdTag[i].textContent = dict2[textToCheck];
  }
}` 
This is what I will do but it doesn't check for inclusion, and need equality in key in dict to work. Not sure how much help that is.